# How do i use newton's method to calculate the value of 10^1/3 to two decimal place?

Tags: calculus

I'm so confused i can't derive this

newton's method requires = x0 - f(x0)/f'(x0) it needs a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a function that evalates to 0 for the solution.

So how about:

$$ x^3 - 10 $$

These days, you have YouTube for explanation of Newton's method:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uN8cBGVpfs

By the way, find your typo in your question first.

Comment: I don't get how calculating 10^1/3 connects to the newton method

Comment: the above function has a 'root' at $10^{1/3}$, as desired.

Comment: Ah yes x0=2 leads to 13/6 then x1=13/6 leads to 2.15 as required =)

Comment: Indeed, but you also have to take one step more so 2.15 would still return 2.15, to prove sufficient convergence.